# How to ignore some Tkinter collisions?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I've got a grid on my canvas, and in some cells, circles. My goal is to move circles around the grid but not over another circle. So when I'm moving the circle I check if there's something on its way, if so, cancelling the movement. Firstn I tried to check collision at the end of the movement, but I couldn't get it to work. So I'm trying to check while moving, but I realized that canvas lines are also objects, so there are collisions. 
Is there any "simple" way to ignore these lines collisions but not the circles ones ?

```
class Deplacement:
def __init__(self, canvas, event):
    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.obj = "à déterminer"
    self.obj2 = "à déterminer"
    self.couleur = "à déterminer"
    self.couleur2 = "à déterminer"
    self.collision = "à déterminer"
    canvas.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
    canvas.bind("B1-Motion", self.OnMotion)
    canvas.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)

def StartMove(self, event): #Getting the object I want to move
    self.x = event.x
    self.y = event.y
    self.obj = self.canvas.find_overlapping(self.x - 15, self.y - 15, self.x + 15, self.y + 15) 

def OnMotion(self, event): #This is where I struggle
    #Trying to get the second circle if it exists
    self.obj2 = self.canvas.find_overlapping(event.x - 15, event.y - 15, event.x + 15, event.y + 15)
    if not self.obj2:
        self.collision = False
    else:
        self.collision = True

def StopMove(self, event): #This works fine, in context, checking items colors to move them or not
#And objects must be moved by one axis
    self.couleur = self.canvas.itemcget(self.obj, "fill")
    if not self.collision:
        if self.couleur == 'black' or self.couleur == 'white' or self.couleur == 'red':
            if event.x > self.x and self.y - 10 <= event.y <= self.y + 10:
                self.move(event, self.obj)
            elif event.x < self.x and self.y - 10 <= event.y <= self.y + 10:
                self.move(event, self.obj)
            elif event.y > self.y and self.x - 10 <= event.x <= self.x + 10:
                self.move(event, self.obj)
            elif event.y < self.y and self.x - 10 <= event.x <= self.x + 10:
                self.move(event, self.obj)

def move(self, event, obj): #Finally moving objects, works nicely aswell
    self.x = (event.x - 20) // 50 + 1
    self.y = (event.y - 20) // 50 + 1
    self.obj = obj
    if event.x < 20:
        self.x = 1
        self.canvas.coords(self.obj, self.x * 50 - 25, self.y * 50 - 25, self.x * 50 + 15, self.y * 50 + 15)
    elif event.y < 20:
        self.y = 1
        self.canvas.coords(self.obj, self.x * 50 - 25, self.y * 50 - 25, self.x * 50 + 15, self.y * 50 + 15)
    elif event.x > 470:
        self.x = 9
        self.canvas.coords(self.obj, self.x * 50 - 25, self.y * 50 - 25, self.x * 50 + 15, self.y * 50 + 15)
    elif event.y > 470:
        self.y = 9
        self.canvas.coords(self.obj, self.x * 50 - 25, self.y * 50 - 25, self.x * 50 + 15, self.y * 50 + 15)
    else:
        self.canvas.coords(self.obj, self.x * 50 - 25, self.y * 50 - 25, self.x * 50 + 15, self.y * 50 + 15)
```

PS: Ignore French words.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the variable named `canvas` is an instance of Tkinters' Canvas class.  You didn't show the code that populates the canvas, but I assume you populate it with method calls such as `canvas.create_line()` or `canvas.create_oval()` and so on.  Each of these methods returns an integer which is the ID of the created shape.  What you must do is to store the IDs of shapes that you want to ignore, in other words, create a set of shape IDs that should not constitute a collision.  Let's say you put those into a set named `ignore_these`.

The method `find_overlapping` returns a tuple of shapes that overlap with the specified rectangle.  Suppose we call this returned value `possible_collisions`.  So to tell if you have a collision you just need a line of code something like:

```
if any(s not in ignore_these for s in possible_collisions):
    # handle the collision
else:
    # go ahead and make the move
```

This is a two-step process (create the set of non-colliding shapes and then use it to analyze the results of find_overlapping).  You asked for a simple way of doing this but I doubt if there's a way to avoid these two steps; Tkinter has at least given you the hooks you need to write the necessary logic.

Manual reference: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas

Comment: It is probably easier to maintain a set of the shapes that do collide and run the collision tests on this collection only - it will make simpler and avoid repeated filtering operations.

Comment: I don't see why it's simpler or why it would change the amount of filtering.  It's only a question of whether there's a True or a False in your logic.  In either case you have to filter every time you want to make a move.  Since the question was how to "ignore" some collisions, I wrote the answer in terms of a set of the objects to-be-ignored rather than a set of those not-to-be-ignored.

Comment: no, you must maintain two collections and check only the collisions on the one containing the colliding items.

Comment: I created these two collections, the first one collecting all lines I'm creating (ignored collisions). The second one is created while moving, adding every object id that    find_overlapping finds. Then I tried to use the pseudo-code you gave me, it still moves when I move one circle over another one, which is not supposed to happen. Here's what I changed [link](http://pastebin.com/q8bi6VNj)

Comment: @Hedowas I don't see where you populate self.ignore.  The method find_collisions does NOT return an object, but a TUPLE of shape IDs.  This tuple could be empty.  You want to build collections of shape IDs, not collections of tuples.  The collection should have the logic of a set. i.e., no duplicates.  As your program stands, your variable possible_collisions is long list of tuples,  You test each tuple for membership in self.ignore.  I don't know what's in either collection, so I can't say what the any() statement should do.  Trying printing out the values.

Answer (score 0):

When you add items to the canvas, the methods used return a unique id for these objects (an integer). You must gather these ids in a collection, with an additional collection for the ids of the items that do collide. (you could segregate the items that do not collide, but you would have to filter them every time you run the collision detection part)

This is pseudo-code:

```
def create_canvas_objects(self):
    id = canvas.create_object()
    self.all_canvas_objects_ids.append(id)
    if object_collides:
        self.colliding_objects.append(id)

def check_collisions(self):
    for object in self.colliding_objects:
        check the collision
```

This way, you filter the colliding vs. the non colliding objects only once at their creation, instead of every frame.

Comment: I think I understand what you meant, but the items do not collide when they are created, so there would not be any colliding objects in the process. [link](http://i.imgur.com/aSFQBxs.png?1)
That's what it looks, like, so no collisions at start

Comment: Yes, there are no collisions at the start, but you already know for which type of items you want to track collisions (circles) and for which ones you don't. You add all the objects ids in the `all_canvas_objects_ids`, and the circles also in the `colliding_objects` collection. Now, you only have to track the circles for collisions, instead of all the objects.

Comment: So I have to check for every event in my     OnMotion function if that the overlapping object is in the    colliding_objects collection. But if I do so, when my pointer moves by a circle to a non-colliding cell, the movement is allowed, isn't it ?

Comment: No, the `on_motion` method will only check the objects in the `colliding_objects collection`, not the other ones that do not collide.